# Movie with flying ship and color changing hair

Tags: story-identification, animation

From what I remember:

There was scene where two characters are on a flying ship in the air, and staring out into the sky. I also remember something about reverse aging and the girl's hair turning white to brown for some reason so that she could be with the other character.

It's an animation film and I'm 70% sure it wasn't made in the 2000's. Or it could be, but I remember it being an old movie.

It also didn't seem like an American or British animation, probably Korean. But it was in English, so please help. It's bothering me so much!

Comment: It was in English because it was distributed by Disney, and they employed a ton of good actors (most notably Christian Bale as Howl), so the film has a perfect English dub.

Answer (score 34):

Are you thinking *[Howl's Moving Castle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0347149/)*?

[image: Poster for Howl's Moving Castle]

Sounds like it could be your film.  Sofi is a teenage girl who is aged by a spell, and she reverts on occasion into her younger self, typically when she's with Howl, the magician.   They fly on a winged contraption at one point after fleeing the Queen's castle.

Comment: I think this is definitely the movie described by @Abiii. And like most Studio Ghibli movies, it did receive a theatrical release of its English dubbed version, as well as a bilingual home video release. The sense that it was older animation could come from Studio Ghibli's trademark character design and animation style, which hasn't changed much in decades.

Comment: I later thought that it could be because the book on which is was based was from 1986 and the setting is mid 20th century...ish.

Comment: Howl's castle didn't actually fly but walk. But There are also a lot of flying warships.

Comment: @algiogia Not trying to spoiler, but it still matches over the course of the movie

Comment: I came here to answer just by seeing the title, but you've already done that!  I love this movie and watched it like 10 times

Comment: @private_meta you're right. Forgot that.