# Movie Identification: Old woman, walking house, and bird guy?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember seeing a cartoon or anime movie when I was little(maybe six or seven) about a young woman who was cursed to look and feel like an old woman. She discovers a walking house in her travels as an elder. The inhabitant of the house is seen in a dream as a demon bird/man fleeing down a dark tunnel. I can't remember the name of the movie.

Comment: What year would you have been six or seven? For me that would have been late 1970s, which rules out a huge number of animated movies!

Comment: I would have been six in the year 2007.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117213/movie-with-flying-ship-and-color-changing-hair

Answer (score 25):

That could be [Howl's moving castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howl%27s_Moving_Castle_(film)), which has a girl transformed into an old woman, a walking castle, and a man turning into a bird monster.  It came out in 2004.

[image]

[image]